# Android (Dalvik) member variable access performance

Tags: android, dalvik

I just did a benchmark to compare access performance of local variables, member variables, member variables of other objects and getter setters. The benchmark increases the variable in a loop with 10 mio iterations. Here is the output:

BENCHMARK: local 101, member 1697, foreign member 151, getter setter 268

This was done on a Motorola XOOM tablet and Android 3.2. The numbers are milliseconds of execution time. Can anybody explain the deviation for the member variable to me? Especially when compared to the other object's member variable. Based on those figures it seems to be worthwhile to copy member variables to local variables before using their values in calculations. Btw, I did the same benchmark on an HTC One X and Android 4.1 and it showed the same deviation.

Are those numbers reasonable or is there a systematic error that I miss?

Here is the benchmark function:

```
private int mID;

public void testMemberAccess() {
    // compare access times for local variables, members, members of other classes
    // and getter/setter functions
    final int numIterations = 10000000;
    final Item item = new Item();
    int i = 0;

    long start = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(); 
    for (int k = 0; k < numIterations; k++) {
        mID++;
    }
    long member = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - start;

    start = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(); 
    for (int k = 0; k < numIterations; k++) {
        item.mID++;
    }
    long foreignMember = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - start;

    start = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(); 
    for (int k = 0; k < numIterations; k++) {
        item.setID(item.getID() + 1);

    }
    long getterSetter = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - start;

    start = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(); 
    for (int k = 0; k < numIterations; k++) {
        i++;
    }
    long local = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - start;

    // just make sure nothing loops aren't optimized away?
    final int dummy = item.mID + i + mID;  
    Log.d(Game.ENGINE_NAME, String.format("BENCHMARK: local %d, member %d, foreign member %d, getter setter %d, dummy %d",
            local, member, foreignMember, getterSetter, dummy));
}
```

Edit: 
I put each loop in a function and called them 100 times randomly. Result: 
BENCHMARK: local 100, member 168, foreign member 190, getter setter 271
Looks good, thx.
The foreign object was created as final class member, not inside the functions.

Comment: You should run each test in its own method to avoid optimisation interference and you should try to vary the order in which they are run. Ideally you should also monitor GC.

Comment: +1 Good question! Makes you think.

Comment: A smart compiler could eliminate the loop and replace it with `i += numIterations`.  That might even extend to getters/setters declared within the same class.  I suspect that sort of thing is chiefly done to make benchmarks like this report absurdly good numbers. :-)  One reason to use a high number of iterations is that the JIT won't compile anything until the code is "hot", i.e. it's run a lot; you should probably run this entire method twice.  You can also be affected by CPU frequency adjustments (for power saving or thermal throttling).

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'd say that the Dalvik VM's optimizer is pretty smart ;-) I do know that the Dalvik VM is register-based. I don't know the guts of the Dalvik VM, but I would assume that the following is going on (more or less):

In the **local** case, you are incrementing a method local variable inside a loop. The optimizer recognizes that this variable isn't accessed until the loop is completed, so can use a register and applies the increments there until the loop is complete and then stores the value back into the local variable. This yields: 1 fetch, 10000000 register increments and 1 store.

In the **member** case, you are incrementing a member variable inside a loop. The optimizer cannot determine whether or not the member variable is accessed while the loop is running (by another method, object or thread), so it is forced to fetch, increment and store the value back into the member variable on each loop iteration. This yields: 10000000 fetches, 10000000 increments and 10000000 store operations.

In the **foreign member** case, you are incrementing a member variable of an object inside a loop. You have created that object within the method. The optimizer recognizes that this object cannot be accessed (by another object, method or thread) until the loop is completed, so can use a register and apply the increments there until the loop is complete and then store the value back into the foreign member variable. This yields: 1 fetch, 10000000 register increments and 1 store.

In the **getter/setter** case, I am going to assume that the compiler and/or optimizer is smart enough to "inline" getter/setters (ie: it doesn't really make a method call - it replaces `item.setID(item.getID() + 1)` with `item.mID = item.mID + 1`). The optimizer recognizes that you are incrementing a member variable of an object inside a loop. You have created that object within the method. The optimizer recognizes that this object cannot be accessed (by another object, method or thread) until the loop is completed, so it can use a register and apply the increments there until the loop is complete and then store the value back into the foreign member variable. This yields: 1 fetch, 10000000 register increments and 1 store.

I can't really explain why the **getter/setter** timing is twice the **foreign member** timing, but this may be due to the time it takes the optimizer to figure it out, or something else.

An interesting test would be to move the creation of the foreign object out of the method and see if that changes anything. Try moving this line:

```
final Item item = new Item();
```

outside of the method (ie: declare it as a private member variable of some object instead). I would guess that the performance would be much worse.

Disclaimer: I'm not a Dalvik engineer.

Answer (score 0):

Beside varying their order, there are other things that you can do in order to try to eliminate any interference:

1- Eliminate the border effect by calculating the first item a second time; preferably by using another long variable.

2- Increase the number of iterations by 10.  1000000 seems a big number but as you can see from the first suggestion; increasing a variable 1 million times is so fast on a modern CPU that a lot of other things like filling the various caches take their importance.

3- Add spurious instructions like inserting dummy `long l = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()-start` calculations.  This will help showing that this 1000000 iterations is really a small number.

4- Add the `volatile` keyword to the `mID` field.  This is probably the best way to factor out any compiler or CPU related optimization.

Comment: Re #4, `volatile` carries a lot more baggage in Java than it does in C/C++.  On a multi-core device -- which nearly all Android devices are now -- the VM will have to add CPU memory barriers to every access.  (See http://developer.android.com/training/articles/smp.html .)